# In C++ how to know till where the array is filled

Tags: arrays

If a array of size 10 is given in the problem and it is filled till an unknown index continuously starting from zeroth index then how to find till which index the array is filled.

As per my knowledge there is no inbuilt function for this.
As array is already been filled so we cannot keep track till where the array is filled by using a variable.

Comment: What do you mean with "filled"? A value other than previous gargabe? Other than null? Or zero? But I don't see why you can't use a variable to track that yourself.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. An array is never "not filled". You need to be more precise in what exactly you mean with "filled" when an array is "a contiguously allocated nonempty sequence of objects" (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array)

Comment: You can't. An array is just a slice of memory. How you interpret the memory in that location is totally up to you.